# Are APM measured in game time or real time?

Tags: starcraft-2

If I have 100 APM in Starcraft 2, do I click 100 times per minute or actually 140 times. The multiplier for faster is about 1.4 X.

I heard that these two times are called "game time" and "real time".

I would also want to know in what time Sc2gears measures its APM.

I do not care about small differences due to different spam prevention mechanisms etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [TeamLiquid wiki](http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft2/APM), Starcraft's APM numbers are based on Normal Game Speed.

So if you want to convert this to real time from "faster" time (the default ladder speed), you would multiply by 1.38.

Answer (score 7):

The concept of APM is independent from Starcraft and from Blizzard, so it cannot be based on Blizzard's "in-StarCraft2" game time...

However the APM values seen when watching a replay are calculated by StarCraft II using game time. This makes these APM values incomparable to values seen/coming from other games.

There are tools which can calculate and show APM values using "real" or normal time, [Sc2gears](https://sites.google.com/site/sc2gears/) is for one. Sc2gears can calculate and show APM values using both game time and real time (you have the option to choose, real time is the default).

The Sc2gears home page has a nice description about the different types of APM (including info what you can see in StarCraft 2 and how they relate to the Sc2gears APM values):
https://sites.google.com/site/sc2gears/features/replay-analyzer/apm-types

Comment: Welcome to Arqade, we prefer answers that have a bit more content than a link. Can you flesh this out a bit?